# List Mails by subject

Tags: shell-script, scripting, mutt

I'm writing a script to send mails from a mailbox on a remote server and a script to check if the mails are received at another remote server. For this I have configured mutt.

What I now need is to list all mails from the mailbox with a specified subject from the command line. I couldn't find a command option to list mails from cli so I think I have to configure mutt to use Maildir and `grep` files but I'm not sure if that's the best way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect use for [notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org) or even neomutt [virtual-mailboxes](https://neomutt.org/feature/notmuch)

1. install notmuch
2. `notmuch setup`
3. `notmuch new` #needed everytime you fetch emails - ideal to hook after mail sync
4. You're done, you can search, count or whatever you want to.

example:

```
$ notmuch search subject:"[neomutt/neomutt] NeoMutt core dumps on F28 beta (#1126)"
thread:00000000000009f4   2018-04-21 [11/11] Suvayu Ali, Pietro Cerutti, Richard Russon; [neomutt/neomutt] NeoMutt core dumps on F28 beta (#1126) (Maillists)

$ notmuch count subject:"[neomutt/neomutt] NeoMutt core dumps on F28 beta (#1126)"
11
```